# HTTP REST: OK to return different keys in response body depending on response size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, aws-lambda

I'm working with AWS Lambda which has a response payload size limit of 6 MB.

In some cases, a call to my function will return a response that exceeds this limit.
To combat this, I've instead resorted to sending URL to the API consumer so they can download this larger file themselves in these cases. I do not know which input will exceed the limit.

A few approaches I have in mind:

- Never send the actual data, but instead always send the URL to keep the response layout consistent. I don't actually want to do this because it will be a performance hit.
- Implement pagination by sending a token the consumer can use for the next call to get the next set of results. This will possibly be slower than letting the consumer download the large file themselves.
- Allow the response to not be consistent in its layout. In the case of exceeding payload size, return a URL, and in the case of non-exceeding, simply provide the payload.

What is the "correct" way to do this, (according to the HTTP spec)?

Comment: What do you have in that file (json something) ? Where do the files stored ? For the first approach, why do you think "it will be a performance hit" ?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the "correct" way to do this, (according to the HTTP spec)?

Depending on your definition of "correct", [redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) may be what you are looking for.

HTTP gives us semantics for telling general purpose components to send a request *somewhere else*.  From your description, you probably want [302 Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3).

There's an additional question as to whether you want to include that metadata in your payload?  In other words, do you need to extend the schema of your response so that a client, looking at the *body* of the HTTP response, can know that they are supposed to go look somewhere else for the data?

And you can do that, by designing a schema where various fields are optional, rather than guaranteed; so one of the optional fields is the data, and another optional field is a link to the data, and the client code knows what to do because the answer is right there in the message.

(On the web, this looks like a page that sometimes has what you want, and sometimes has "this page has moved" with a link).

Answer (score 0):

If storing the data elsewhere is a possibility, and consumers will usually want the entire dataset I would be tempted to just *always* use that approach so there's never any surprises for the consumer.

You could do this with a `303 See Other` HTTP response.

There's also nothing wrong from a HTTP perspective to do different things depending on the payload size, but from a developer ergonomics perspective I think I would prefer to see 1 consistent way to respond vs. having to deal with 2 cases from a consumer perspective.